# Tag email posts in Google Groups

Tags: google-groups, google-groups-tags

Is it possible to tag email post in Google Groups? I am able to tag new post that I create but am not seeing the tag option on topics that came in from email.

Answer (score 1):

From [Tag topics - Groups Help](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1047904?hl=en)

> Note: You must be the creator of a topic to add tags to the topic.

If you are the creator of the topic

> To tag a topic after a topic has been created:
>
> 1. From the Topic screen, click on the 'add tags' link next to the
>      topic's title. The Edit Tags dialog box appears.
> 2. Click on the tags (in blue; next to "suggested tags") you want to add to the topic. Tags appear in the field as they are added.
> 3. Click Save changes. Tags are added to the topic.