# How do I tag a Google Group post that is posted via email?

Tags: google-groups

We have a Google Group that accepts posts via email. Posts can also be tagged.

Is there a way to tag posts by including some data in the email? For example `mygroup+tag-mytag@googlegroups.com`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43210/google-groups-tags

Comment: kind of. I want to tag them automatically with the email that's sent to the group email address. That link shows how to tag it from the google groups interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there isn't a way for the email sender to assign a Google Groups tag to the emails that are being sent to a Google Group.

---

From [Tag topics - Groups Help](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1047904?hl=en)

> Note: You must be the creator of a topic to add tags to the topic.

If you are the creator of the topic

> To tag a topic after a topic has been created:
>
> 1. From the Topic screen, click on the 'add tags' link next to the
>      topic's title. The Edit Tags dialog box appears.
> 2. Click on the tags (in blue; next to "suggested tags") you want to add to the topic. Tags appear in the field as they are added.
> 3. Click Save changes. Tags are added to the topic.

Comment: Most of the content of this answers was originally posted as an answer to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/43210/88163 but it doesn't have any vote yet.